# HasMany and WithRequired extension methods not found

Tags: entity-framework, ef-model-builder

I am building my data layer class library with Entity Framework 6.1. I created my context and am trying to do the model builder code (or is it derived when I do Add-Migration?

Anyway, I have seen quite some examples but when I try to use .HasMany or .WithRequired on a modelBuilder.Entity() instance they don't appear in Intellisense. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Entity<T>` method is generic ([DbModelBuilder.Entity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696542(v=vs.113).aspx)), so, you need to specify the `T` type you want to start your configuration, for example:

```
public class Foo
{
  public in Id{get;set;}

  public in BooId{get;set;}

  public virtual Boo Boo{get;set;}
}

public class Boo
{
  public in Id{get;set;}

  public virtual ICollection<Foo> Foos{get;set;}
}
```

And the configuration on the `OnModelCreating`method would be:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().HasRequired(f=>f.Boo).WithMany(b=>b.Foos).HasForeignKey(f=>f.BooId);
```

Comment: That is what I was using, the generic method but now that I see, the .With* () extension methods appear only after HasRequired